# Java - Why HttpClient doesn't send my cookies?

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient

I try to send cookies with a form post using the Apache HttpClient and, for some reason, the server gets the request but not the cookies. Here is my code:

```
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Set the cookies...
            {
                String Domain = MyGetParameter("Domain");
                BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
                String[] strs = GetParameterSplitted("PostCookies");
                int size = strs.length;
                for (int i=0; i<size-1; i+=2)
                {
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strs[i]+" = "+FromBase64(strs[i+1], "UTF-8"));
                    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(strs[i], FromBase64(strs[i+1], "UTF-8"));
                    cookie.setDomain(Domain);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    //cookie.setSecure(true);
                    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
                }
                client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
            }

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url.toURI());
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(10);
            // Set the form POST parameters...
            {
                String[] strs = GetParameterSplitted("PostParams");
                int size = strs.length;
                for(int i=0; i<size-1; i+=2)
                {
                    String name = strs[i].trim();
                    String value = FromBase64(strs[i+1].trim(), "UTF-8");//, "UTF-8"

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
                }
            }
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            post.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            post.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int StatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The site uses HTTP (not HTTPS), I make sure the domain name is set correctly to the cookies (`http://mysite`) and the cookies seem to be set correctly when the above code executes.

Does anyone have any idea why it's failing to pass them to the server?
I have seen other similar questions on this site but nothing seemed to help.

Comment: Are you sure the cookies come from the exact same domain that you are sending to? For example `http://stackoverflow.com` and `http://www.stackoverflow.com` are different domains.

Comment: Yes. Actually, I don't think that the request would even reach the server if the POST url was different. I debug the site locally.
I set the cookie domain as `http://mysite` and I post the form at `mysite/blah/blah`. I don't think the `http://` part plays any role, does it?

Comment: Do I need to set the path like that: `cookie.setPath("/blah/blah");` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You look closely, if the date of your cookie expired httptClient not send this cookie, on this that you should put the cookies date.

And in domain name will be no "http://", only simply domain name.

For Example:(http://www.gmail.com => like this to write **setDomain(**"www.gmail.com"**)**)

This example i add 100 day to current day and set cookie.
Example send post data via HttpClient with cookie:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 100);
Date date = calendar.getTime();

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
httpClient.setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore());
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(YourCookieName, YourCookieValue);
cookie.setDomain(YourDomain);
cookie.setExpiryDate(date);
cookie.setPath("/");
httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookie);

....

httpClient.execute(yourHttpUriRequest);
```

Comment: Ha! That was it!
It was the `http://` in the cookie domain that made things fail...
Thanks.

Comment: man you saved my life, struggled for 12 hrs and found I included https:// in the domain name.

Comment: Thanks @Guanlun, I am glad that my question helped to you

Comment: Thanks for a domain, it helped me.